# How to do diagonal & irregular lines in CSS & HTML backgrounds / divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have seen this in many websites so far, but I have no idea how it's done. I am wondering how [here, in this image, which is a screenshot of the digitalocean website,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wlnP.jpg) the diagonal lines in the background are made? I know how to set the background of a div to a gradient or just a plain uniform color, but how do you do stuff like that?

There are also [two sections separated like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXgfq.png). So instead of the separation being a straight line between two divs, there is a bump in there. I have no idea how things like this are implemented from a coding perspective and don't know what I should google to find out more. (I'm not even sure if these two things call for a similar solution) Thanks a lot for your understanding.

Comment: That is most likely just an image fixed position to top right..

Comment: they are using 2 background images on the startpage so i would assume that they are using it everywhere

Comment: Have you attempting anything so far?

Comment: The lines are just part of the banner image https://www.digitalocean.com/assets/media/v4/hero-images/spaces-2b070cd0.svg

Comment: Perhaps this is a more suitable question for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to imgur, but I think I see what you're asking. Something like that ?

```css
.diag {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 0, #fff 281px, #ddd 282px, #fff 283px, #fff 566px);
  background-size: 400px, 400px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="diag"></div>
```

About the "bump", a simple SVG can manage that I guess. But you can't do it with a non-image background property, I'm sure of that !